# Doxygen malfunction due to forward declaration

Tags: c++, doxygen

the Doxygen output is bugy due to the forward declaration in the header "fileA.h"

It starts with the doxygen Class List where for Class A the header-description does not appear

[image: Class List: fileA description not visible]

And than the copyright and author strings of fileA are displayed in the member function Documentation.

[image]

When i include the header-file with the #include directive instead of the
forward declaration everything is correct. But in the final project i need to use forward declaration
due to ring-includes.

For Class B without forward declaration everything looks like expected

[image]

I use doxygen 1.9.5

Here is the sourcecode for this little example:

*Sources for fileA.h*

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * @copyright        Copyright (c) 2021
 *******************************************************************************
 * @author  Mr. Embedded
 *
 * @brief This description and the copyright and author info
 * shall be displayed in the doxygen "class Referece" in the section "Detailed Description"
 * for all classes that are declared in this header-file.
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
#ifndef _FILE_A_H
#define _FILE_A_H

// forward declaration
class B;

class A{
public:
   B *b;
   void test(void);
};

#endif
```

*Sources for fileA.cpp*

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * @copyright        Copyright (c) 2021
 *******************************************************************************
 * @author  Mr. Embedded
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

#include "fileA.h"
#include "fileB.h"

/*******************************************************************************
 * @brief test Dummy
 ******************************************************************************/
void A::test()
{
   b = new B;
   b->test();
}
```

*Sources for fileB.h*

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * @copyright        Copyright (c) 2021
 *******************************************************************************
 * @author  Mr. Embedded
 *
 * @brief This description and the copyright and author info
 * shall be displayed in the doxygen "class Referece" in the section "Detailed Description"
 * for all classes that are declared in this header-file.
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
#ifndef _FILE_B_H
#define _FILE_B_H

class B{
public:
   void test(void);
};

#endif
```

*Sources for fileB.cpp*

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * @copyright        Copyright (c) 2021
 *******************************************************************************
 * @author  Mr. Embedded
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

#include "fileB.h"

/*******************************************************************************
 * @brief test Dummy
 ******************************************************************************/
void B::test()
{
}
```

and the doxyfile differece with the default doxyfile

```
$ doxygen -x doxyfile
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.5 (87846a24ba5d96a548e5e1a377c2ff078a77dd77)
SHORT_NAMES            = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
JAVADOC_BANNER         = YES
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = h=C++
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
INPUT                  = fileA.h \
                         fileA.cpp \
                         fileB.h \
                         fileB.cpp
RECURSIVE              = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH    = 10
```

Comment: Is this the complete Doxyfile, as it looks to me being cut-off. Best is to present the results of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` i.e. the differences with the default Doxyfile. The documentation on top of the files `fileA.h` and `fileB.h` is this intended for the `class A` / `class B`? if this is correct the documentation fore the class A should be directly in front of the `class A` or have the line (in this case `\class A` before `fileA.h`. The `\brief` doesn't come through as brief either as the line `fileB.h` is seen as brief description here.

Comment: I have updated the example according to your suggestions.
The documentation on top of the files `fileA.h` and `fileB.h` shall be displayed in the `Detailed Description Section` of the class Reference.

Comment: @albert if insert the `\class A` command at the beginning of the header description than the `Detailed Description Section` appears however `\copyright` and `\author` still appears in the Member function documentation of `A::test()`

Comment: @albert Sorry now i see why `\copyright` and `\author` appears again in the Member function documentation. The reason is that i included `\copyright` and `\author` again in the source file and doxygen links this to the first member definition.

Comment: Ar5e there still questions left?

Comment: no questions left, thanks for your support.